# Text that shows an underline on hover

Tags: html, css

Can you underline a text on hover using css?  (Like the behavior of a link but not an actual link.)

1. you have the following text  Hello work
2. when you hover your mouse over the text it underlines it using css

(the text is not a link)

Comment: There's nothing remotely unclear to me about the question.  If this question is unclear to someone, it may be because they know nothing about CSS.

Comment: FWIW, I googled "css underline hover" and that's exactly how I got here, first result. :-)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

```
<span class="txt">Some Text</span>

.txt:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

You just need to specify `text-decoration: underline;` with [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) `:hover`.

### HTML

```
<span class="underline-on-hover">Hello world</span>
```

### CSS

```
.underline-on-hover:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I have whipped up a working **[Code Pen Demo](http://codepen.io/ryanw/pen/oDtik/)**.

Comment: Devs may also want to combine this with the `text-decoration-color` CSS property to override the default blue appearance and match the color to the text you are underlining

Answer (score 13):

Fairly simple process I am using SCSS obviously but you don't have to as it's just CSS in the end!

### HTML

```
<span class="menu">Menu</span>
```

### SCSS

```css
.menu {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: blue;
    transition: all .35s ease;

    &::before {
        content: ""; 
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: yellow;
        visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
        transform: scaleX(0);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; 
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; 
    }   

    &:hover {
        color: yellow;

        &::before {
            visibility: visible;
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
            transform: scaleX(1);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: This unlike the accepted answer works in the Edge browser! upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

```css
li {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:15px;
}

li:hover {
  color: Blue;
  border-bottom: 3px solid Blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello work</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.resume_link:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: rgb(250, 114, 64);
  -moz-text-decoration-color: rgb(250, 114, 64);
  text-decoration-thickness: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="resume_link">Resume</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<span class="text">Click Me</span>

.text:hover {
    text-decoration: underline black //This colour is an example
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 