# How to make an underlined link on hover without text-decoration

Tags: html, css

[image: Navbar Mockup]

Hello everyone, i made this navbar mockup and im starting coding it. but i didn't know how to make the line under the link when i hover at it. The line should be sticked to the bottom of the navbar. any help ? im using html and css.

Comment: look it, pls - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674633/text-that-shows-an-underline-on-hover

Comment: Welcome to SO! I always recommend new users review [ask] for tips on forming their questions in a manner that best enables the community to provide assistance.  Generally, you'll want to include a [mcve] (preferably as a snippet), with a clear explanation of the desired behavior (using visual aids if helpful), the actual behavior, and how they differ.  With the question as it is currently written, there is no code for the community to work from, and the desired behavior is not clear (to me, at least).  Try updating with this in mind, and hopefully we can help.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: You can use border-bottom with hover

Comment: You can also use <span></span> at the end of <li>. You could set the style of <span> so that <span> can be work as underline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pseudo elements (:before, :after).

Using them gives you the ability to create intricate and more complicated effects than a simple underline and also add animation effects (fade in etc.), without the need for JS.

Just remember to always use the `content` attribute.

HTML
`<span class="text">text</span>`

CSS

```
.text {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block
}

.text:hover:after{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #000;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your image I think you are using `li` tags. You can use [CSS hover pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) to apply styles on hover

Try this

```css
li {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:15px;
}

li:hover {
  color: orange;
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one extra div within the li and give that div styles according to your need. On hover it will be appear and while you away the mouse it will disappeared.
You can consider this following code.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="navbar-container">
<ul>
    <li class="nav-link active-link">
        <a href="#">Home
        </a>
        <div class="underline"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
        <div class="underline"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
        <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
        <div class="underline"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <div class="underline"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS Code:

```
body, html {
margin: 0;
font-family: Roboto, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
outline: none;
}

.navbar-container {
text-align: center;
background-color: #009688;
box-shadow: 0px -20px 5px 20px #333333;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 0;
}

.navbar-container ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-container ul li {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar-container ul li a {
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;  
padding: 10px;
transition: color 0.5s;
}

.navbar-container ul li .underline {
height: 3px;
background-color: transparent;
width: 0%;
transition: width 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-container ul li.active-link .underline {
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
}

 .navbar-container ul li:hover .underline {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 }

 .navbar-container ul li:hover a {
 }

 .navbar-container ul li:active a {
transition: none;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.76);
}

.navbar-container ul li:active .underline {
transition: none;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.76);
}
```

JavaScript/Jquery Code:

```
$('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
$('.active-link').removeClass('active-link');
$(this).addClass('active-link');
});
```

Live Example: https://codepen.io/hayzey/pen/LNzwVO

Comment: thank you that worked! I just changed a bit in the css code