# Changing an element inside a component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the react code that I wrote. What it does is it renders 3 unordered list elements () each having a heading.

What I want is to have an underline below the link having the text Terms and conditions. Is there any way to do this?

```
import React from "react";

const FooterLinksBox = () => {
  const footerLinksData = [
    {
      title: "Quick Links",
      links: ["Features", "Pricing", "Schedule a demo", "Chat Support"],
    },
    {
      title: "Privacy Policy",
      links: ["Terms and Conditions", "Privacy Policy", "Refund Policy"],
    },
    {
      title: "Support",
      links: ["Book a demo", "Customer Support", "FAQs"],
    },
  ];

  const footerLinksCard = footerLinksData.map(({ title, links }) => {
    return (
      <div className="footer__links_card">
        <h4 className="footer__heading">{title}</h4>
        <ul className="footer__list">
          {links.map((link) => (
            <li>
              <a href="/">{link}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div className="footer__links">{footerLinksCard}</div>;
};

export default FooterLinksBox;
```

Comment: Can you clarify it a little. What I don't understand is that there's only one <a> tag and it renders all the other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a bold class to those relevant anchors.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const footerLinksData=[{title:"Quick Links",links:["Features","Pricing","Schedule a demo","Chat Support"]},{title:"Privacy Policy",links:["Terms and Conditions","Privacy Policy","Refund Policy"]},{title:"Support",links:["Book a demo","Customer Support","FAQs"]}];

function Example() {
  
  const footerLinksCard = footerLinksData.map(({ title, links }) => {
    return (
      <ul>
        {links.map(link => (
          <li>
           {link === 'Terms and Conditions'
            ? <a className="bold" href="/">{link}</a>
            : <a href="/">{link}</a>}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  });

  return <div className="footer__links">{footerLinksCard}</div>;
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.bold:hover { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match the text and change style of the component

```
<li>
     <a href="/" style={{textDecoration:(link === "Terms and Conditions"? "underline":"auto")}}>{link}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks this works! But what if I want underline to be only there on the hover?

Comment: you should add the [class with hover effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674633/text-that-shows-an-underline-on-hover).

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try to put a class for "Terms and Conditions" and use that class to underline.(using text-decoration: underline).

{links.map((link) => (
        <li>
          <a className={link ==="Terms and Conditions" && "underline-cls"} href="/">{link}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
or you can use inline-styling and use textDecoration.
```

Comment: can you define what is after className in the curly braces {}

Comment: The curly braces are a special syntax to let React know that it needs to interpret the contents in between them as JavaScript instead of a string.
Here I have used JavaScript logical statements inside HTML, so I need to use curly braces.